# Type annotations for decorators

Tags: python

It is not a big problem, but I just wondered the way to solve this.
Since I am new to using function annotations on Python, I am not familiar with it. And I have a question below.

When you make a decorator and want to put the annotation on it, how do you do that?

For example, codes like below.

```
def decorator(func: Callable[[*args,**kwargs], <what type should be here?>]) -> <??>:
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func
```

Comment: Hint: decorators are just a short hand for `func = decorator(func)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

I actually think `@Nikola Benes` has the correct answer instead of me, namely:

[`PEP 612`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) introduced `ParamSpec`, which provides the ability to *define dependencies between the parameters of callables*.

Below is one way you could have *tried* to do it before `ParamSpec`, but `ParamSpec` is the way to go.

For those using Python <3.10, you *should* be able to get `ParamSpec` it from `typing_extensions`

```py
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec
```

but I've not experimented with it. It might also depend on whether your static type checker (e.g. `mypy`, `pyright`, etc.), and the version of that checker, has implemented support for it.

The first part of the [PyCon 2022 Typing Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G-67gGgTl0) video recording shows `ParamSpec` in action.

---

#### Old Workaround:

Use `Any` for the return type and return another `Callable` of return type `Any`. From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable) and the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable), the first parameter to `Callable` must be the *types* of the arguments to the callable, not the arguments themselves. Hence, your use of `*args` and `**kwargs` in `Callable` is unaccepted. Instead, you must use ellipses `...` (which permits any number of positional and keyword argument types).

Decorator functions are more cleanly expressed using generic types (`typing.TypeVar`). In layman's terms, a generic is something that allows a type to be a parameter.

Paraphrasing from the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators) (**FYI**: `mypy` is a static type checker package for `python`):

> Decorator functions can be expressed using generic types. Generics can
> be restricted to using values that are subtypes of specific types with
> the keyword argument `bound=...`. An upper bound can be used to
> preserve the signature of the wrapper function a decorator decorates.

Hence, your example becomes this:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, cast

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def decorator(func: F) -> F:
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return cast(F, new_func)
```

Also paraphrasing from the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators) and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable):

> The bound on `F` is used so that calling the decorator on a
> non-function will be rejected. Also, the wrapper function (`new_func`)
> is not type-checked because there is (currently) no support for
> specifying callback signatures with a variable number of arguments of
> a specific type, so we must cast the type at the end.

Answer (score 18):

Note that [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) (which is implemented in Python 3.10) introduces `ParamSpec`, which solves your problem like this:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def decorator(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    def new_func(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_func
```